# Backup contacts sample code or example from iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icloud, addressbook

I want to take backup of my iPhone contacts using iCloud. How it is possible to take a backup programmatically in my iPhone application? Is there any sample code or example?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. You can use (or have your users use) iCloud to back up their addresses. You can access the address book by using the address book API.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these two steps:

1. Retrive data from address book, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744
2. And the store retrieve data to iCloud
   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloud101/Introduction/Introduction.html